# MS SQL Query to get the data before underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field of data which consists of FullName like this

```
Vinod_Patil
Santosh_Reddy
Sandeep
```

Looking to separate the data before the underscore so executed following query

```
FirstName = SUBSTRING(FullName,0, CHARINDEX('_', FullName) ),
```

Where FullName is the column name

Result is

```
Vinod
Santosh
-
```

So for the data Sandeep, it displays special character"-"

Expected Result

```
Vinod
Santosh
Sandeep
```

how do I modify the above query to display the data if it does not have any underscore?

Best regards,
Vinod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @sampleData TABLE (FullName varchar(100));
INSERT @sampleData VALUES ('Vinod_Patil'),('Santosh_Reddy'),('Sandeep');

-- Solution
SELECT FullName = SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', FullName),0),100)-1)
FROM @sampleData;
```

Results:

```
FullName
-------------------
Vinod
Santosh
Sandeep
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case
         when CHARINDEX('_', FullName) > 1 then SUBSTRING(FullName,0, CHARINDEX('_', FullName) )
         else FullName
       end as FirstName
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
SELECT FirstName = SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX('_', FullName + '_') - 1),
```

There are three changes:

- The second argument to `CHARINDEX()` has a `_` appended.  This ensures that the character is found, so conditional logic is not necessary.
- The `- 1` subtracts the separation character.
- The second argument is "1" and not "0", because `substring()` starts counting at "1".

Answer (score 0):

Look at this query, if charindex > 0, you can use your substring function, else you can use another substring function with empty space to get only the first name.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_', User_FirstName) > 0 THEN 'with special char' ELSE 'Non special char' END AS FirstName FROM Users
```